# php round up / ceil merge mysql AVG()

Tags: php, mysql, rounding, ceil

or Show Average i have this :

```
$item = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(top) AS total FROM " . "$config_ccms_prefix" . "news where id='$id'"); 
while ($cms = mysql_fetch_assoc($item)) {
            $avg = ceil(($cms[total]),0.5);
        }
//......
```

example :
i need to round up if $ccms[total] = 3.4 to 3.5 or 7.8 to 8 or 9.3 to 9.5 BUT not round 9.5 to 10 or 4.5 to 5 .Actually, I'm not sure it is possible.

$avg not work for me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this then:

```
$avg = ceil($cms['total']*2)/2; //result of
```

Results will be:

```
1.5 = ceil(1.1*2)/2; //CEIL(2.2) = 3.0 / 2 = 1.5;
1.5 = ceil(1.2*2)/2; //CEIL(2.4) = 3.0 / 2 = 1.5;
1.5 = ceil(1.3*2)/2; //CEIL(2.6) = 3.0 / 2 = 1.5;
1.5 = ceil(1.4*2)/2; //CEIL(2.8) = 3.0 / 2 = 1.5;
1.5 = ceil(1.5*2)/2; //CEIL(3.0) = 3.0 / 2 = 1.5;
2 = ceil(1.6*2)/2; //CEIL(3.2) = 4.0 / 2 = 2;
2 = ceil(1.7*2)/2; //CEIL(3.4) = 4.0 / 2 = 2;
2 = ceil(1.8*2)/2; //CEIL(3.6) = 4.0 / 2 = 2;
2 = ceil(1.9*2)/2; //CEIL(3.8) = 4.0 / 2 = 2;
2 = ceil(2*2)/2; //CEIL(4) = 4.0 / 2 = 2;
```

Cheers

Comment: Good one;-) Then in MySQL you could do this - SELECT CEILING(x * 2) / 2;

Comment: Indeed, it's just a math operation

Answer (score 0):

Also that function can be helpful

```
// duplicates Excel's ceiling function
if (!function_exists('ceiling')) {
    function ceiling($number, $significance = 1) {
        return (is_numeric($number) && 
            is_numeric($significance) ) ? 
            (ceil($number / $significance) * $significance) : false;
    }
}
$data = array(1.2, 1.1, 3.5, 3.8, 4, 0.6, 4.1);
foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo $value . ' | ' . ceiling($value, 0.5) . '<br/>';
}
```

This will result in

```
1.2 | 1.5
1.1 | 1.5
3.5 | 3.5
3.8 | 4
4   | 4
0.6 | 1
4.1 | 4.5
```